# Objective C issue with IBaction

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ibaction

I am new to Objective C. In the `UITableViewController` I add `+` and `Edit` buttons connected to my `IBaction`

```
- (IBAction)add:(id)sender {
    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd 
target:self action:@selector(addButtonPressed:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd];
    [button setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    cell.accessoryView = button;
}
```

It gives me two issues `undeclared addButton` and `undeclared cell identifier`. However, I have declared `cell` in the storyboard prototype cell?

Comment: Where is `cell` coming from? And what kind of behaviour are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: The IBaction method is the method that executes when the action is taken (addButtonPressed in your case). This code is the code that is adding your Bar button item. This code should either go in or be called from `viewDidLoad` and is not an IBAction method.  And you can't just arbitrarily refer to some cell object that you haven't defined. Cell modification needs to happen in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: @Paulw11, it is not mandatory, that cell modifications can only happen in cellForRowAtIndexPath, we can modify cells anywhere in the implementation file, only thing is that after modifying we need to reload the table view.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add the following Code in ViewDidLoad.

```
    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd 
target:self action:@selector(addButtonPressed:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
```

and make one IBAction For "addButtonPressed"

```
-(IBAction)addButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
// your code
}
```

and you use tableview custom cell then you have to declare and Registered cell Identifier.

e.g

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 Prototypecell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"yourIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd];
    [button setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    cell.accessoryView = button;
}
```

It may be helpful to you..

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `IBAction` might have been created within your **Storyboard**.

If that's the case, meaning you've already added your `UIButton` to the `UIViewController` in **InterfaceBuilder**, you shouldn't have to add a UIButton.

You shouldn't have to call the method: `addButtonPressed:` using a `@selector` either. Instead, **remove** the code being executed in your `addButtonPressed:` method and **add** it into your `IBAction` method like so:

```
- (IBAction)add:(id)sender {

    //  Code from
    //  AddButtonPressed:
    //  Goes here

}
```